What's wrong with my MOSFET H-Bridge design?
My classmate and I designed this MOSFET H-Bridge to control a 12V DC motor:

We performed a simulation of the transistors' behaviour in NI Multisim. Below are the results.

When all switches are OFF:



When S1 is ON and S2 is OFF:



When S1 is OFF and S2 is ON:



When all switches are ON:


We tested it out using a solderless breadboard and it worked just as intended. We were able to easily control the motor's spin direction and speed.

However, after assembling it on a PCB and testing it out, the circuit becomes shorted, and the MOSFETs heat up aggressively. Below is the board layout on Autodesk EAGLE:

And here is the board fully solded and assembled. Note that I have cut the 10k resistors near the flyback diodes to see if that was causing the issue, which was not the case.

We're struggling to find out what went wrong.

I strongly suggest that you simulate your design and debug at that level before committing to a circuit board design. In not simulating you have bypassed a vital step in the design process.

I simulated the design in NI Multisim and assembled it in a breadboard without any issues. The issues arose only after committing to the PCB

Please add the simulation circuit to your question.

I have just added screenshots of the simulation in Multisim, I appreciate your feedback.

That looks right but, because you don't need to have the diodes D1-D4 I suggest you remove them and retest the PCB @vic then, try testing it with the lower side MOSFETs removed and see if there is still a power supply short and excessive warming.

The P-ch and N-ch gates are connected each other, during the transitions/switching when the gates are at ~6V both fets are conducting, creating a shot-through.
By controlling gates through 10K resistors (slow) makes things worst , because shot-through occurs longer time.
You should implement a dead-time to the design, or avoid the simultaneous fets conduction by using fets threshold “feature”.

Thanks a lot for the feedback! The circuit gets shorted as soon as I activate my power source, would this fix that issue as well? Also, how would I go about implement the dead-time other than removing the 10k resistors? Could you please provide some sort of schematic. Again your reply is much appreciated!

Also, is there any way to correct the issue without adding any components? The PCBs have already been manufactured and I would really like to avoid ordering new ones. Thanks a lot!

First, left and right sides should be inverted, so when left P-ch is On the right N-ch should be On. You switch both sides the same.


Please show waveforms of simultaneous voltages at Q1 collector, Q2 drain, Q3 source.  2. Is there a capacitor close to each switching arm that filters the supply voltage?  3. I am struggling to understand why the solderless breadboard was OK.  Are you sure the circuits on the breadboard and the PCB are identical?


When S1 or S2 or both are open, the bjt are not polarized i.e. the Vbe is floating. Something is missing.

The circuits on the breadboard and the PCB were based on the same schematic and are identical.
